# About left cell of a permutation

Tags: co.combinatorics, algebraic-combinatorics, hecke-algebras, kazhdan-lusztig

I am reading a paper Cellular algebras by J.J. Graham, G.I. Lehrer. I do not understand the follwing words labelled by yellow.

[image]

First, I know Robinson-Schensted correspondence of a permutation in the symetric group $\textrm{Sym}(\bf n)$.

For example, in $\textrm{Sym}(\bf 3)$, a permutation $\binom{123}{312}$ corresponds to a pair $(S,T)$ of standard tableaux. If $T$ correspond to the left cell of $\binom{123}{312}$ and $S$ to the right cell, I need to know whether $T$ is 
\begin{array}{cc}
& 1  & 2 \\ 
& 3  & 
\end{array} and $S$ is 
\begin{array}{cc}
& 1  & 3 \\ 
& 2  & 
\end{array}?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The KL right cell is the collection of permutations that have the same insertion tableau S from RSK algorithm, the left cell is those of the same recording tableau T.
KL right(left) cell are the equivalence classes of KL right(left) preorder on $\mathfrak{S}_n$.

The S of 312 is :
$$1 \;\; 2$$
$$3\;\;\;$$
The T is:$$1 \;\; 3$$
$$2\;\;\;$$